# Exlude duplicate data Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table called ITEMS contains four fields "TrainsactionID", " Date","Item", and "Total".
In this table, I found more than one record has the same TransactionID. I want to select all records of the table ITEMS and if more than one record has the same TransactionID, then I want to take the TransactionID which has the lowest "Total". For example, consider these records:

```
TId   Date       Item   Total
111   1/1/2011   A       $200
112   2/1/2011   B       $150
111   1/1/2011   A       $120
113   5/1/2011   N       $500
```

I want my query result to return:

```
112   2/1/2011   B       $150
111   1/1/2011   A       $120
113   5/1/2011   N       $500
```

i.e, it ignores the first record because there is another Transaction with the same TID but with lower total price.

Please help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT MyTable.TId, MyTable.Date, 
       MyTable.Item, Min(MyTable.Total) AS MinOfTotal
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyTable.TId, MyTable.Date, MyTable.Item;
```